# how to curve a line in a trapezoid css

Tags: css

please tell me how I can make the same trapezoid as in the picture, this is what I got, but this is not at all what I need in the end

```
.trapezoid {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(245deg);
  border: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, white 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 73% 9%, 67% 49%, 73% 85%, 0% 100%);
border-radius: 20px; /* Один радиус для всех углов */
}
```

What is needed in the end result

[image]

what happened (wrong)

[image]

please tell me how I can make the same trapezoid as in the picture, this is what I got, but this is not at all what I need in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a vector graphics editor to design the shape you want, then export the shape as an SVG. You can either:

1. Reference the SVG from an `<img>` tag
2. Insert the SVG inline (with the `<svg>` tag)
3. You can copy the path definition from the SVG and use it in a `clip-path` style rule.

```css
.trapezoid {
  background: blue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  clip-path: path('M 200.794 85.264 C 207.78 89.297 214.904 92.527 222.19 94.534 C 250.642 102.372 250 122.851 250 122.851 L 250 228.181 C 250 228.181 250.623 252.399 222.412 248.813 C 137 239.037 59.8 185.137 22.931 105.544 C 11.226 76.733 42.58 69.715 42.58 69.715 L 128.583 40.824 C 128.583 40.824 154.559 31.237 165.815 51.006 C 173.884 65.178 186.181 76.828 200.794 85.264 Z');
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, is there any way to implement through pure css?

Comment: You can extract the path from the SVG and put that into a `clip-path` style rule. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much, can we make the size 100x100? 
250x250 is a big size for me.

Comment: No, I'm just showing you what to do, I'm not going to do it for you. [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com) is a fantastic SVG editor. Start with that.